# want to convert list to string for below example

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting a result set from one column `df['Test'].head()`:

```
0    [fed, official, say, weak, data, caused, weather, slow, taper]     
1    [fed, 's, charles, plosser, see, high, bar, change, pace, tapering]
```

I want to convert it as below and store in the same column as:

```
fed official say weak data caused weather slow taper
fed 's Charles plosser see high bar change pace tapering
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `' '.join()` on each of the rows of the dataframe?

Comment: yes tried but getting error  ', '.join(s)  ERROR - name 'fed' is not defined

Comment: What did you already tried? We're here to help, not doing the work for you ;)

Comment: The data inside list should be of datatype string, i.e. enclosed in quotes like `"data"`. So make your list like this - `["fed", "official", .....] `.

Comment: can you show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows() : 
  s = ''
  for i in row['Test'] : 
    s = s + i
  df['Test'][index] = s
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I am tried with df['Test'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))

Answer (score 2):

Use `.apply(" ".join)`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas  as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [['fed', 'official', 'say', 'weak', 'data', 'caused', 'weather', 'slow', 'taper'],
                            ['fed', "'s", 'charles', 'plosser', 'see', 'high', 'bar', 'change', 'pace', 'tapering']
                           ]
                })
print(df["Test"].apply(" ".join))
```

**Output:**

```
0    fed official say weak data caused weather slow...
1    fed 's charles plosser see high bar change pac...
Name: Test, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

As your format of list is not proper,

first I converted into list of words and then converted to string.

**Code:**

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': ["[fed, official, say, weak, data, caused, weather, slow, taper]",
                            "[fed, 's, charles, plosser, see, high, bar, change, pace, tapering]"
                           ]
                })

>>> df['Test']=df['Test'].str[1:-1].str.split(', ').apply(' '.join)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
                                                Test
0  fed official say weak data caused weather slow...
1  fed 's charles plosser see high bar change pac...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help.

df['Test'].apply(lambda x: " ".join([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split()]))

its worked for the above scenario.